# React AWS CSS url background SVG is moving on dev not on producion (or after build)

Tags: css, reactjs, amazon-web-services, svg

a use this url, you can unparse it online and beautify, it is moving on dev but not after a build.

Please if you have any idea let me know, thank you

background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:svgjs='http://svgjs.com/svgjs' width='1440' height='560' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 1440 560'%3e%3cg mask='url(%26quot%3b%23SvgjsMask2503%26quot%3b)' fill='none'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='560' x='0' y='0' fill='url(%23SvgjsRadialGradient2504)'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3cpath d='M1295.557%2c351.535C1319.485%2c349.527%2c1340.112%2c337.042%2c1353.14%2c316.871C1367.611%2c294.466%2c1378.5%2c266.533%2c1365.498%2c243.245C1352.277%2c219.564%2c1322.674%2c213.238%2c1295.557%2c213.728C1269.458%2c214.199%2c1244.452%2c224.051%2c1229.859%2c245.694C1213.226%2c270.362%2c1202.698%2c302.9%2c1218.389%2c328.178C1233.58%2c352.651%2c1266.853%2c353.944%2c1295.557%2c351.535' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float3'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M461.684%2c598.727C514.835%2c595.74%2c558.027%2c560.952%2c584.97%2c515.039C612.309%2c468.45%2c627.485%2c410.483%2c599.129%2c364.506C571.74%2c320.098%2c513.851%2c314.218%2c461.684%2c315.143C411.634%2c316.031%2c361.036%2c328.155%2c332.432%2c369.236C299.265%2c416.87%2c283.325%2c479.816%2c311.809%2c530.39C340.688%2c581.666%2c402.928%2c602.029%2c461.684%2c598.727' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float2'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M1441.403%2c441.103C1489.338%2c439.333%2c1538.488%2c423.557%2c1561.771%2c381.619C1584.522%2c340.639%2c1568.876%2c292.622%2c1546.788%2c251.281C1522.907%2c206.584%2c1491.978%2c159.558%2c1441.403%2c156.337C1386.543%2c152.843%2c1337.562%2c188.697%2c1309.884%2c236.192C1281.999%2c284.042%2c1274.67%2c344.509%2c1304.585%2c391.117C1332.694%2c434.912%2c1389.398%2c443.023%2c1441.403%2c441.103' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float3'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M723.455%2c450.266C744.599%2c450.437%2c764.597%2c439.639%2c775.042%2c421.254C785.369%2c403.078%2c785.093%2c379.939%2c773.165%2c362.771C762.534%2c347.469%2c742.071%2c346.226%2c723.455%2c347.001C706.575%2c347.704%2c689.964%2c352.681%2c680.434%2c366.632C669.497%2c382.642%2c664.426%2c403.189%2c673.295%2c420.431C682.833%2c438.973%2c702.605%2c450.097%2c723.455%2c450.266' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float1'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M1117.045%2c707.103C1171.885%2c706.291%2c1202.841%2c650.233%2c1228.93%2c601.989C1253.276%2c556.967%2c1275.908%2c504.773%2c1250.479%2c460.354C1224.942%2c415.747%2c1168.423%2c405.061%2c1117.045%2c406.554C1068.737%2c407.958%2c1021.029%2c426.156%2c996.399%2c467.737C971.33%2c510.06%2c977.127%2c561.465%2c999.267%2c605.391C1024.29%2c655.038%2c1061.454%2c707.927%2c1117.045%2c707.103' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float2'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M1362.578%2c545.211C1385.211%2c543.569%2c1404.364%2c530.56%2c1416.236%2c511.222C1428.786%2c490.779%2c1435.229%2c465.957%2c1424.363%2c444.571C1412.543%2c421.308%2c1388.668%2c406.105%2c1362.578%2c405.621C1335.658%2c405.121%2c1310.596%2c419.146%2c1296.688%2c442.201C1282.296%2c466.058%2c1278.49%2c496.652%2c1293.503%2c520.123C1307.651%2c542.241%2c1336.391%2c547.11%2c1362.578%2c545.211' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float2'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M172.646%2c101.722C197.648%2c100.359%2c220.046%2c88.363%2c233.758%2c67.413C249.115%2c43.949%2c259.641%2c14.281%2c245.862%2c-10.143C231.92%2c-34.855%2c201.02%2c-40.947%2c172.646%2c-40.911C144.352%2c-40.875%2c114.973%2c-33.806%2c99.748%2c-9.958C83.458%2c15.557%2c82.247%2c49.418%2c98.794%2c74.768C114.146%2c98.288%2c144.601%2c103.25%2c172.646%2c101.722' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float3'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M150.443%2c144.16C165.353%2c143.951%2c175.638%2c130.956%2c182.914%2c117.941C189.966%2c105.327%2c194.687%2c90.336%2c187.565%2c77.762C180.365%2c65.051%2c165.049%2c60.303%2c150.443%2c60.614C136.437%2c60.912%2c123.038%2c67.195%2c115.964%2c79.287C108.822%2c91.494%2c109.721%2c106.383%2c116.359%2c118.872C123.475%2c132.261%2c135.281%2c144.372%2c150.443%2c144.16' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float1'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M621.532%2c539.928C638.722%2c539.309%2c651.398%2c525.485%2c659.484%2c510.303C667.012%2c496.168%2c668.293%2c479.851%2c661.166%2c465.509C653.109%2c449.297%2c639.63%2c434.415%2c621.532%2c433.933C602.798%2c433.434%2c586.999%2c446.822%2c578.065%2c463.296C569.562%2c478.975%2c569.735%2c497.702%2c578.535%2c513.216C587.458%2c528.947%2c603.459%2c540.578%2c621.532%2c539.928' fill='rgba(122%2c 155%2c 192%2c 0.4)' class='triangle-float2'%3e%3c/path%3e%3c/g%3e%3cdefs%3e%3cmask id='SvgjsMask2503'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='560' fill='white'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3c/mask%3e%3cradialGradient cx='100%25' cy='50%25' r='1466.97' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' id='SvgjsRadialGradient2504'%3e%3cstop stop-color='rgba(94%2c 127%2c 160%2c 1)' offset='0'%3e%3c/stop%3e%3cstop stop-color='rgba(94%2c 137%2c 193%2c 1)' offset='1'%3e%3c/stop%3e%3c/radialGradient%3e%3cstyle%3e %40keyframes+float1 %7b 0%25%7btransform: translate(0%2c 0)%7d 50%25%7btransform: translate(-10px%2c 0)%7d 100%25%7btransform: translate(0%2c 0)%7d %7d .triangle-float1 %7b animation: float1+5s+infinite%3b %7d %40keyframes float2 %7b 0%25%7btransform: translate(0%2c 0)%7d 50%25%7btransform: translate(-5px%2c -5px)%7d 100%25%7btransform: translate(0%2c 0)%7d %7d .triangle-float2 %7b animation: float2 4s infinite%3b %7d %40keyframes float3 %7b 0%25%7btransform: translate(0%2c 0)%7d 50%25%7btransform: translate(0%2c -10px)%7d 100%25%7btransform: translate(0%2c 0)%7d %7d .triangle-float3 %7b animation: float3 6s infinite%3b %7d %3c/style%3e%3c/defs%3e%3c/svg%3e");

Answer (score 0):

so i had to add ";utf8" at the begining of the url(

instead of: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg  ->url("data:image/svg+xml **;utf8** ,%3csvg